# How does Keras accuracy metric compare to custom metric for CNN Lane Detection?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I've read multiple answers to the question surrounding the 'accuracy' metric used in Keras but I'm not entirely confident I understand what this means in terms of lane detection. Does the Keras metric compare the pixels detected in the prediction equal to the pixels in the ground truth and divide by total number of pixels? Or is it necessary to create a custom metric that does this?

Answer (score 1):

From [keras' github](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/tree/master/docs):

> ```
> Calculates how often predictions matches labels.
> For example, if `y_true` is [1, 2, 3, 4] and `y_pred` is [0, 2, 3, 4]
> then the accuracy is 3/4 or .75.  If the weights were specified as
> [1, 1, 0, 0] then the accuracy would be 1/2 or .5.
> ```

So it all depends on how you describe the target vector, i.e. the values obtained from the output layer. Let's assume, that you have a 255x255 image, where, in a matrix form, 1 represents a line, and 0 represents no-line. Vectorizing it into a vector of length 255*255 = 65025 would result in a binary vector. Then, for each accuracy measurement, keras compares your model's prediction (where it put the line) with the original (test) data, and computes the accuracy.

Please note, that for such large data, there are many transforms to reduce the size of the model, and many interesting papers describe various methods.

Comment: In terms of pixel value, if it were comparing the prediction and ground truth would it class it as a match if say the pixel were value 240 compared to 255 in the ground truth or do the intensities have to match?

Comment: well, if you consider such vector [240, 255, 239, 243] and true vector [255, 255, 255, 255], the accuracy would be only 1/4. You can always round the values (0 or 255 with threshold in 128), and then this predicted vector would be [255, 255, 255, 255] as well.